# How to display data only once by using two different tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, group-concat

I am preparing register that input from  date and to date...That display the entries made by the user from date and to date...I want to display voucher no,billdate,qty,amount(present in purchase bill table) and product name(present in purchaseitem table) i want to print the product name on the same row according to the billno..(For this i am using group concat)...My problem is all the datas are displaying multiple times..I don't know where is the error in my code..What changes have to be done on my code to display the data only once..Below i have attached my code..Help me

Controller Code:

```
$this->db->where('date >=', $newDate);
        $this->db->where('date <=', $newDate2);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('purchasebill');
        $this->db->order_by("voucherno", "asc");
        $this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = purchasebill.partyname','left outer');
        $this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(Prdtname)as itemname',false);
        $this->db->order_by('vno','asc');
        $this->db->group_by('vno,billno');
    $this->db->from('purchaseitem');


    $query = $this->db->get('')->result_array();    
    $data ['query']= $query;
```

View code:

```
  <?php $rowcount = 1 ?>                            
                                <?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?=$rowcount;?></td>
                                            <td><?=$row['voucherno'];?></td>
                                            <td><?=$row['date'];?></td>
                                            <td><?=$row['PName'];?></td>
                                            <td><?=$row['sqty'];?></td>
                                            <td><?=$row['billtot'];?></td>
                                            <td><?=$row['itemname'];?></td>
                                            <?php $rowcount +=1?>
                                            <br>
                                            <?php endforeach ?> 
                                        </tr>
```

I think the datas are printing multiple times because i have used two queries but passed on the same variable $data..Is there is any possibility to load multiple query result on the same view page..???

Comment: Can you show how you're passing the $data array to the view and also your view code?

Comment: Yeah sure...check on my edited post

Comment: Ok, so your view looks fine. I'm almost completely sure the problem is in the query, have you tried your query on PhpMyAdmin or similar?. Use `echo $this->db->last_query();` after your `$query = $this->db->get('')->result_array();` line and then copy that line and try directly on the database, you may be getting duplicated rows there.

Comment: Yeah sir..I tried groupconcat in phpmy admin there it works fine..Is there is any possibility to load two query results on the same view page because for both of the table i am using $query and pass it on data

Comment: Now that I see, your sql query builder looks wrong, there's 2 selects and no clear way on how they should be executed. You can totally separate those queries, but first let's make sure you find the right SQL query. How does `purchasebill` links with `purchaseitem`.

Comment: In both the table voucher no is saved

Comment: Yeah..Is there is any possibility two load two queries in the name of query 1 and query but on the same view page..??

Comment: And you want the purchasebilll with the details of every item I guess. Yes, you can perform more than 1 query, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Yeah sir this is what exactly want..Thanks for the response..i am waititng for your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->where('date >=', $newDate);
    $this->db->where('date <=', $newDate2);
    $this->db->select('purchasebill.*,GROUP_CONCAT(parmaster.Prdtname)as itemname');
    $this->db->from('purchasebill');
    $this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = purchasebill.partyname','left outer');
    $this->db->order_by('vno','asc');
    $this->db->group_by('vno,billno');


$query = $this->db->get()->result_array();    
$data ['query']= $query;
```

Comment: getting this error Not unique table/alias: 'purchasebill'

SELECT `purchaseitem`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(parmaster.Prdtname)as itemname FROM (`purchasebill`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `parmaster` ON `parmaster`.`Pcode` = `purchasebill`.`partyname` LEFT OUTER JOIN `purchasebill` ON `purchasebill`.`date` = `purchaseitem`.`billdate` WHERE `date` >= '2018-11-09' AND `date` <= '2018-11-12' GROUP BY `vno`, `billno` ORDER BY `vno` asc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can execute different queries and pass them individually to the view:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('purchasebill');
$this->db->where('date >=', $newDate);
$this->db->where('date <=', $newDate2);
$this->db->order_by("voucherno", "asc");
$this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = purchasebill.partyname','left outer');
$query1 = $this->db->get()->result_array();

$this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(Prdtname) AS itemname',false);
$this->db->order_by('vno','asc');
$this->db->group_by('vno,billno');
$this->db->from('purchaseitem');
$query2 = $this->db->get()->result_array();  

$data['bills']= $query1;
$data['items']= $query2;

$this->load->view('your_view_path', $data);
```

Then on your view, you can access the data in `$bills` and `$items`. My advice is that you play around and create just one query that brings all your information.

Comment: getting error..undefined variable query1 and invalid argument supplied foreach

Comment: I am trying to achieve this through one query but i don't know how to fetch two datas from two different table..

Comment: If you're getting undefined query1 you need to debug what's being returned to `$query1`, where are you getting this error? in your view?

Comment: I am getting nothing in my view page..It's just displaying me the error undefined variable query1 and query 2..and i calculate total at the end of my page... and i am getting total and error in my view page

Comment: Are you using `$query1` and `$query2` in your view? You should be using `$bills` and `$items`.

Comment: @dhara if you can share your code somewhere I'd be glad to review it and offer feedback so you can finally find a solution.